# Join two tables: all rows from the first with a sub-set from the second

Tags: sql-server-2005

This should be simple but no matter what I try I can't get the data I want...
I have two tables:

**dependent d**

```
empID  relID      dob
100     1     8/8/1988
100     2     1/1/2001
200     1     9/9/1989
```

**employee e**

```
empID
100
200
300
```

that I need to join like so:

**Desired Results** (where only dobs with relID=1 are included)

```
e.empID  d.dob
100     8/8/1988
200     9/9/1989
300     NULL
```

No matter which join I use I end up with only the records that intersect (where the empID in dependent has a record with relID=1) like so:

**Actual Results** (see query below)

```
e.empID  d.dob
100     8/8/1988
200     9/9/1989


SELECT e.empID, d.dob 
FROM employee AS e LEFT OUTER JOIN dependent AS d ON e.empID = d.empID
WHERE (d.relID = 1)
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thank you for your kind attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the filter part of the join condition:

```
SELECT e.empID, d.dob 
FROM employee AS e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dependent AS d 
ON e.empID = d.empID
AND d.relID = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm embarassed to say how long I puzzled over this but an easy answer is most welcome!